# Syncfusion rich text editor angular 9 iFrame won't work in material components

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, syncfusion, rich-text-editor

Receiving the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
at IframeContentRender.renderPanel (ej2-richtexteditor.es2015.js:14123)
```

when loading in the @syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor inside a mat-tab-group. The contentWindow is null.

Seeing some comments on this thread: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/138651/configure-rich-text-editor with no luck.

Any ways around this?

Comment: We have validated your query “When rendering the Rich Text Editor with Iframe enable inside the Accordion console error occurs”.  
  
We tried all the feasible ways to reproduce the issue by rendering the Rich Text Editor with Iframe inside the Accordion. Also, we configured the specified version of angular and Rich Text Editor. But we are unable to reproduce the issue from our side.  
  
We have prepared a sample for your reference,  
Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4g87r-4rntfc?file=app.component.ts

Comment: This is an issue with using the syncfusion rich text editor inside an Angular Material tab group: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview